# error while read/write (Hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I followed [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) tutorial to install hadoop. Well, everything works fine if I use \usr\local\hadoop as hadoop.tmp.dir. since I have very little space in this partition, I tried to set this value to /NEW_partition/(ext4) but I was always getting some java error. I guess this is because hadoop is not able to write to this partition. How can I make it work?

::::EDIT::::
complete execution result.

```
hadoop@FreeLnx:/usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203.0$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.203.0.jar wordcount /MY_STORAGE/tmp1/gutnb /MY_STORAGE/tmp1/gutnbou


12/02/12 02:56:00 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3

12/02/12 02:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201202120255_0001

12/02/12 02:56:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

12/02/12 02:56:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)


12/02/12 02:56:09 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_0&filter=stdout

12/02/12 02:56:09 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_0&filter=stderr

12/02/12 02:56:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_1, Status : FAILED

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)


12/02/12 02:56:15 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_1&filter=stdout

12/02/12 02:56:15 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_1&filter=stderr

12/02/12 02:56:21 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_2, Status : FAILED

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)


12/02/12 02:56:21 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_2&filter=stdout

12/02/12 02:56:21 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000004_2&filter=stderr

12/02/12 02:56:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)


12/02/12 02:56:33 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_0&filter=stdout

12/02/12 02:56:33 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_0&filter=stderr

12/02/12 02:56:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)


12/02/12 02:56:39 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_1&filter=stdout

12/02/12 02:56:39 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_1&filter=stderr

12/02/12 02:56:45 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)


12/02/12 02:56:45 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_2&filter=stdout

12/02/12 02:56:45 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://FreeLnx:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201202120255_0001_m_000003_2&filter=stderr

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201202120255_0001

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 4

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=24115

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0

12/02/12 02:56:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
```

Comment: INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201202112219_0001_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

Comment: what does the job log file say?

Comment: no error logs .. just some new attemp_{Job_ID}_* blank directories are created ..
Additionally I re executed the program and added to the description ..

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to check your permissions for the configured mapred.local.dir directories, the default of which is ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local. The parent directory and all the contents must be owned by the user that runs the TaskTracker daemon, for tasks to be able to write transient data (and do other things) within it effectively.